# Copy database between Heroku environments using Heroku Scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to copy the Postgres database from a production environment to a test environment, but it doesn't seem that the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command) is available on the Heroku app server (`heroku run bash`, then try running `heroku`).

Ideally I could do this using [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler), but for now I'm running this command locally:
`heroku pg:copy [myapp]-prod::postgresql-[stack]-[id] postgresql-[stack]-[id] --app [myapp]-test`

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Heroku CLI doesn't need to be on heroku server, It should be installed on your development machine to interact with heroku cloud. You have to install heroku toolbelt https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

Comment: and then you can import/export or backup/restore your pg data though command line. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#restoring-backups & https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Comment: Yes, I can do it locally. But how do you recommend setting up a backup through Heroku Scheduler?